# Dataframe Transformation in python using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe in following format:

**Date**              **Category**         **Value**
01-01-2020                A                  1
02-01-2020                A                  1
01-01-2020                B                  2
02-01-2020                B                  2

And i need to transform above df in such way that it gives the below output:

**Date**              **Category_A**          **Category_B**
01-01-2020                1                         2
02-01-2020                1                       2

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You can use pandas pivot table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a full example using pandas `pivot_table`:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Date':['01-01-2020','02-01-2020','01-01-2020','02-01-2020'],'Category':['A','A','B','B'],'Value':[1,1,2,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
new_df = pd.pivot_table(df,values='Value',index='Date',columns='Category').rename(columns={'A':'Category_A','B':'Category_B'})
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
Category    Category_A  Category_B
Date                              
01-01-2020           1           2
02-01-2020           1           2
```

I am using `rename` because otherwise the column names will be those of the original values for the `columns`, in this case:

```
Category    A  B
Date            
01-01-2020  1  2
02-01-2020  1  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd

# Supposing that your Data Frame is named df
df_pivot = pd.pivot(df, index='Date', columns='Category', values='Value')
```

You can find the documentation of Pandas' Pivot [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)